# ExecuteMso ("SlidesReuseSlides") does not work anymore

Tags: vba, office365, powerpoint

I have made a PowerPoint add-in for a client. An extra tab is made with company specific buttons/tasks.
I have also put the standard PowerPoint button "Reuse Slides" on that Tab.
Since the latest Office update, this button does not work anymore, I get a runtime error.
I already checked the custom UI, and that is "well formed"

This is the code:

```
Sub Slidesreuseslides()
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("SlidesReuseSlides")
End Sub
```

This is the runtime error I get:

Run-time Error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
Method 'ExecuteMso' of object '_CommandBars' failed

It always has worked perfectly, but now I can't find what is creating this run-time error.
Does anyone know? I would be very grateful!

Best regards, Veronica

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue like you, try using this Argument to call up the ReuseSlide-Blade:

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ReuseSlides")
```

That worked out for me.

Best regards, Michael

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
On Error Resume Next
Err.Clear
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ReuseSlides")
If Err <> 0 Then
   Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("SlidesReuseSlides")
   Err.Clear
End If
```